# JS | Methods | Add the result of two functions in a third function | solution?

Tags: javascript, function, object, methods, addition

Does someone know how to combine two functions in a method? I want to add the result of two different functions in the third function and log it to the console. Thanks for help.

```js
function Circle (radius) {
    this.radius = radius;
    this.area = function () {
        return Math.PI * this.radius * this.radius;
        
    };
    // define a perimeter method here
    this.perimeter = function () {
        return 2 * Math.PI * this.radius;
    }
    this.logg = function() {
        return this.perimeter + this.area;
    }
};

var perimeter = new Circle(12);
perimeter.perimeter();
//doesn't work
console.log(perimeter.logg());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the concatenation of the `toString` result of the functions. You forgot to call the functions - `return this.perimeter() + this.area()`

```js
function Circle (radius) {
    this.radius = radius;
    this.area = function () {
        return Math.PI * this.radius * this.radius;
        
    };

    this.perimeter = function () {
        return 2 * Math.PI * this.radius;
    };
    
    this.logg = function() {
        return this.perimeter() + this.area();
    };
};

var perimeter = new Circle(12);
perimeter.perimeter();
//doesn't work
console.log(perimeter.logg());
```

Comment: Ahhh, it's morning, that's why :) Thanks for a prompt solution.

Comment: Suren Srapyan Sure :)